# Internet Explorer 8 event.wheelDelta issue

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, dom-events, no-framework

Why Internet Explorer 8 with `console.log(event.wheelDelta);` returns null or undefined? How to make him return the correct number with pure Javascript?

```
document.getElementById('div').onmousewheel = function(evt) { console.log(evt.wheelDelta); }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
    function handleMouseWheel(evt) {
      console.log(evt.wheelDelta);
    }

    window.addEventListener('mousewheel', handleMouseWheel, false);
```

Comment: Yes it works, but why this not? document.getElementById('div').onmousewheel = function(evt) { console.log(evt.wheelDelta); }

Comment: Your method should work too, I suspect you are not getting your element correctly. Are you sure your element's id is "div"? Also what is the error message? Make sure document.getElementById('div') is not returning null.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that this doesn't work in firefox.